# Python replacing values between dataframes with different length and types of index

Tags: python, pandas

I have two time-series below. `df1` has a tz-aware DateTime index with a 'Month' column. `df2` has the maximum number of hours per month with months become the index.

**df1**

```
    Month
Timestamp       
2009-01-08 00:00:00+09:30   1
2009-01-09 00:00:00+09:30   1
2009-01-10 00:00:00+09:30   1
2009-04-09 00:00:00+09:30   4
2009-04-13 00:00:00+09:30   4
2009-04-15 00:00:00+09:30   4
2009-10-12 00:00:00+09:30   10
2009-10-16 00:00:00+09:30   10
2009-10-21 00:00:00+09:30   10
```

**df2**

```
    Hour
Month   
1   10
4   9
10  3
```

I want to return `df1` with a new column 'MaxHour' with values taken from the column Hour of the corresponding months in df2. The end result should be like one below.

```
    Month MaxHour
Timestamp       
2009-01-08 00:00:00+09:30   1 10
2009-01-09 00:00:00+09:30   1 10
2009-01-10 00:00:00+09:30   1 10
2009-04-09 00:00:00+09:30   4 9
2009-04-13 00:00:00+09:30   4 9
2009-04-15 00:00:00+09:30   4 9
2009-10-12 00:00:00+09:30   10 3
2009-10-16 00:00:00+09:30   10 3
2009-10-21 00:00:00+09:30   10 3
```

I did like this:

```
df1['MaxHour'] =  df1.loc[df1.Month.isin(df2.index), ['Hour']]
```

resulting different result from what I want.

Comment: just merge? `df1.merge(df2,left_on='Month',right_index=True)` ?

Comment: Two errors. ```KeyError: 'MaxHr'``` and ```ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1```

Comment: Oh.. sorry, by saving it into a new variable, your suggestion works. Thanks.